# google chrome extension manifest v3 context menu create and console command execution on that page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

This is my first chrome extension.
I want to run a console command from the right-click menu, for example a plain hello world. The extension writes to its console. How can I run it on the page where I am? So not in the add-on's console, but on any page where I press the button

manifest.json

```
{
   "name": "Hello",
   "description": "Hello world",
   "version": "0.1.107",
   "permissions": ["contextMenus"],
   "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
   "background": {
     "service_worker": "background.js"
   },
   "manifest_version": 3
 }
```

background.js

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: 'hello',
    title: 'Hello world',
    contexts: ['page']
  })
  
  function contextClick(info, tab) {
    const { menuItemId } = info
  
    if (menuItemId === 'hello') {
      console.log("Hello world");
    }
  }
  
  chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(contextClick);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably looking at a different console.

[image]

Comment: It is indeed there, but I want to write to the console on the given page. How can I do that?

Comment: What is the given page?

Comment: where I just press the button

Comment: so not in the add-on's console, but on any page where I press the button